# Apache Server Install No .msi installer

Tags: apache

I am trying to install apache server from this [Link](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi) using the **NetWare Binary: httpd_2.4.3-netware-bin.zip** link to be precise, I was looking at the internet for a good guide **Not** using the **.msi** installer becouse there is no **.msi** installer at the folder i unzip after i downloaded the zip file from the link above, And becouse i want to learn how to install not using the **.msi** installer at all, So if anyone know a way to install the apache server not using the **.msi** installer i will be very thankful, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are looking for a msi installer, you probably want the win32 version and not the NetWare one. Pick the appropriate one from here: http://ftp.download-by.net/apache//httpd/binaries/win32/

If you want to install without a msi, you still don't want a NetWare version if you are running Windows.

You can read more about the NetWare operating system here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetWare

Comment: Where to find .msi installer? Cann't find in Apache site

Answer (score 0):

More easy install Xammp you have allinone solution for win 32/64 with php version 5.6.3 embed
with:
Backup and Restore MySQL Databases
Configure FTP Access
Configure Virtual Hosts
Configure Wildcard-Based Subdomains
Deploy an Application Using Git
Get Started Quickly with WordPress
Reset the MySQL Root Password
Send Mail with PHP
Troubleshoot Apache Startup Problems

Simple and cool isn't it ??